# Provide binary download links where needed using ASP.NET MVC3 Linq to SQL, maintaining Deferred Loading

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using a VARBINARY(MAX) column to store binary files in a SQL Server table. The other columns in the same table are used to store attributes about the file, such as a description and a time stamp indicating when the file was uploaded.

I created a view in MVC3 that lists the attributes and a link which the user can use to download the binary file. *Some records have a file to download and others do not.*

At first the view rendered very slowly because Linq to SQL was including the binary column in the SELECT clause. I changed the Delay Loaded ([Linq to SQL Deferred Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399393.aspx)) property for the binary column in the domain model to true to prevent this happening.

I needed a boolean to tell me which records actually have a binary so that the download link only appears when there is a file to download so I added a parameter called BinaryExists to my view model.

```
namespace MyProject.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class DownloadsViewModel
    {
        public int DownloadsID { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateUploaded { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Boolean BinaryExists { get; set; }

        public DownloadsViewModel()
        {
        }

        public DownloadsViewModel(Downloads dModel)
        {
            this.DownloadsID = dModel.DownloadsID;
            this.DateUploaded = dModel.DateUploaded;
            this.Description = dModel.Description;
            this.BinaryExists = dModel.Binary != null;
        }
    }
}
```

Adding `this.BinaryExists = dModel.Binary != null;` resulted in Linq to SQL downloading all of the binaries and slowing down the view again.

I want Linq to SQL to provide the boolean indicator without negatively affecting the view performance by downloading the binary. This can be accomplished in T-SQL using the following query.

```
SELECT
    DownloadsID,
    DateUploaded,
    Description,
    CASE
        WHEN Binary IS NULL THEN
            0
        ELSE
            1
        END AS BinaryExists
FROM Downloads
```

The CASE statement provides the boolean trigger for when a download link should be made available without actually having to download the binary first just to check whether or not it exists.

Is there a way to do the same thing in Linq to SQL?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on mutual feedback, here's the most straightforward solution:

Add a new computed column to the database and use the formula: `(CONVERT([bit],case when [Binary] IS NULL then (0) else (1) end,(0)))`.  Set it to "Is Persisted: Yes" for efficiency during querying.  Set the datatype of the column to bit not null so that it maps to a bool in the ViewModel.  Then, you can use that column to gain information about the bigger lazy loaded binary data column.

Comment: Thanks for your response Milimetric. I'm trying to add the ColumnAttribute decoration above the line `public Boolean BinaryExists { get; set; }` but Visual Studio doesn't seem to like it. Where were you suggesting I add it?

Comment: Oops, I needed to add the System.Data.Linq.Mapping namespace. Trying out your suggestion now. :)

Comment: I added `[Column(Expression="CASE WHEN Binary IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END")]` above `public Boolean BinaryExists { get; set; }` but it did not change the query. On the other hand I don't fully understand how to use ColumnAttribute so maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Perhaps it'd be easier to just add that expression as a computed column in the database itself.  Then you can just map to it with a boolean field.

Comment: A calculated column in SQL Server seems to be the most appropriate solution in this case. I created a column named BinaryExists and used the formula `(CONVERT([bit],case when [Binary] IS NULL then (0) else (1) end,(0)))` and I changed the property *Is Persisted* to 'Yes'. I also had to use the null-coalescing operator in the ViewModel to resolve the bool? data type returned to Linq by the computed column `this.BinaryExists = dModel.BinaryExists ?? false;`. If you edit your answer to reflect this solution I'll set the answer as the accepted answer. Thanks!